# FTAs permissible by WTO

Tags: trade, wto

As a WTO member a country attempts to strike bilateral trade deals to augment the baseline trade schedules agreed at the WTO (IIUC).

I read that sectoral free trade agreements (FTAs) are prohibited by WTO under MFN rules [1]. Is this true?

> So, can there be a sectoral FTA? I.e. tariff-free trade
>   in one or a few sectors, or for some companies
>   • NO!
>   • Contravenes MFN principle
>   • Not covered under GATT Article XXIV/GATS
>   Art V
>   • Potentially violates WTO rules on subsidies (SCM
>   Agreement Articles 3.1, 6.1 a and b)
>   • Canada – Autos (2000)

If so, how, for example, is the Japan/EU FTA permitted by the WTO given that tariffs remain on some goods under that deal.

Finally, as a WTO member does a country need to “log” or register with the WTO the FTAs it makes?

**Refs**

[1] Slide 6, http://blogs.sussex.ac.uk/uktpo/files/2017/03/WTO-rules-UK-EU-FTA.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous slide in that presentation says:

> WTO Rules: FTAs
>   • GATT Article XXIV:8(b)
>   • in free trade areas ‘duties…eliminated on
>   substantially all the trade between constituent
>   territories’
>   • Tariffs eliminated in ≥ 90 % of trade
>   • GATS Article V:1(a)
>   • ‘…substantial sectoral coverage’
>   • Constituted by number of sectors, volume of trade
>   affected and modes of supply

So what that means is that a free trade agreement can have exceptions... but these can't be "the rule", they can't dominate the agreement.

I don't know enough about the Japan/EU FTA to say how much in the way of exceptions it has. Presumably since it was not challenged by [anyone at] the WTO (all FTAs of member need to be registered with them) it passes these tests.

There's a 70-page MA thesis published on the [“Substantially all the Trade”-
Requirement of GATT Article XXIV](http://lup.lub.lu.se/luur/download?func=downloadFile&recordOId=1556638&fileOId=1564055), which probably means it's a nontrvial issue. That actually turned out to be pretty weaksauce. http://www.mpil.de/files/pdf3/mpunyb_hilpold_7.pdf is much better; it covers some past disputes etc. on that issue as well as more egregious non-disputed examples.